# Show validation rule error next to the multiple field

Tags: validation, validation-rule, inputfield

The below validation rule works fine but I'm curious to know how can I show the required error message next to the field? As you can see below I have multiple fields and I have selected to show the error on top of the page since I have two fields to validate for `ISBLANK` is that possible in Validation Rule? or do I have to use VF Page to do that?

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed")
,
OR(
 ISBLANK(Completion_Date__c),
 ISBLANK(Last_Completion_Date__c) //you can multiple fields just by adding here....   
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't have a single Validation Rule attach messages to multiple fields. You would either need to make a separate Validation Rule for each field, or do the validation logic in a simple trigger and apply the messages to each field with `record.fieldname.addError(String)`

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to create 2 separate validation rules so that you can apply the error to each field. So instead of the OR condition you would have 2 separate validation rules for each of the Dates.

Answer (score -5):

you can not add error message to multiple fields if you are checking multiple fields in your validation rule. If u want to show error message on multiple fields, then you have to make a trigger for this.
plz mark as answer if it solves your issue.
Thanks